# How to get Percentile data in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I was doing some data analysis. I'm just a beginner to this. Please help me with this problem.

I have a following table, where i want to get the 90 percentile of the `DurationMilliseconds` on a particular day.

```
RowId   Depth   StartMilliseconds   DurationMilliseconds    TxnDate
9869    3       169.8               80056.7                 Jan 19 2015 
9997    3        53                 17593.8                 Jan 19 2015 
10069   3        64.9                63072                  Jan 19 2015 
10950   4        67983.2             2198.9                 Jan 20 2015 
11178   5        2095.7             1886.5                  Jan 20 2015 
11490   3        16.4               818.4                   Jan 20 2015 
11751   5        36                 1955.9                  Jan 20 2015 
11924   5        2078.9             2550.7                  Jan 20 2015 
11998   4        33.4               2071.4                  Jan 20 2015 
12283   3        12                 1241.5                  Jan 20 2015 
12709   5        53                 1480.9                  Jan 21 2015 
12827   3        14.8               501.6                   Jan 21 2015 
13193   5        2667.4             1604.7                  Jan 21 2015 
13315   4         43.1              1646.5                  Jan 21 2015 
13981   4        90                 490.6                   Jan 21 2015 
14050   3        53.2                494                    Jan 21 2015 
14111   4        49                 1464.8                  Jan 21 2015 
14253   4        32                 1576.8                  Jan 22 2015 
14397   3        29.9               484.7                   Jan 22 2015 
14681   5        57.6               1522.6                  Jan 22 2015 
14779   4        45.8               1450.7                  Jan 22 2015
```

The output i want is,

```
Jan 19 2015    90% of DurationMiliseconds?
Jan 20 2015    90% of DurationMiliseconds?
Jan 21 2015   90% of DurationMiliseconds?
Jan 22 2015    90% of DurationMiliseconds?
```

Can someone please suggest me the SQL query for the same?

Comment: What do you mean by 90 value? 90% value?

Comment: Is it `(DurationMilliseconds - StartMilliseconds) * 0.9` ?

Comment: @ CurseStacker  its 90% ...

Comment: the duration in milliseconds column would be useful in your desired output wouldn't it?

Comment: @ Raptor : Ignore Startmiliseconds column..  I want to see the how much time a system is taking at 90% of the time.

Comment: @ Tanner : Ya. i'm using that column to measure the time it took to complete the task.

Comment: question still doesn't make sense. you're simply showing dates in your output and haven't clarified what exactly you want to do with the millisecond column.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT TxnDate, SUM(DurationMS) AS DurationMS, SUM(DurationMS) * 0.9 AS DurationMS90 
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY TxnDate
```

Would output where last column is the 90% of the 2nd column

```
2015-01-19  160722.5    144650.25
2015-01-20  12723.3     11450.97
2015-01-21  7683.1      6914.79
2015-01-22  5034.8      4531.32
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to output 90% of the DurationMilliseconds column value, you could do something like below. You can amend the `CAST` to format number of decimal places as required.

```
GO
DECLARE @DurationMilliseconds AS DECIMAL(19,2) = 80056.7
SELECT CAST(@DurationMilliseconds * 0.9 As Decimal(19,2)) [DurationMilliseconds ]

-- Other way, its same as above but more readable.
SELECT CAST(@DurationMilliseconds * (90.0/100) As Decimal(19,2)) [DurationMilliseconds]
```

So, you need to do something like below:

```
SELECT TxnDate, CAST(SUM(ISNULL(DurationMilliseconds, 0.0)) * 0.9 As Decimal(19,2)) [DurationMilliseconds90percent]
FROM your_table
GROUP BY TxnDate
```